# Ignore KeyError and continue program

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

In Python 3 I have a program coded as below. It basically takes an input from a user and checks it against a dictionary (EXCHANGE_DATA) and outputs a list of information.

```
from shares import EXCHANGE_DATA
portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
print()
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
EXCHANGE_DATA = {code:(share_name,share_value) for code, share_name, share_value in EXCHANGE_DATA}
try:
     for code in portfolio_list:
              share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
              print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value))  
except KeyError:
     pass
```

Example input:
`GPG,HNZ,DIL,FRE`

The output is as follows:

```
Please list portfolio: GPG,HNZ,DIL,FRE

Code  Name                   Price
GPG   Guinnesspeat            2.32
HNZ   Heartland Nz            3.85
DIL   Diligent                5.30
FRE   Freightway              6.71
```

But if I have an input like:

`AIR,HNZ,AAX,DIL,AZX`

where the terms `AAX,AZX` do not exist in the dictionary `(EXCHANGE_DATA)` but the terms `AIR,HNZ,DIL` do. The program obviously would throw a `KeyError` exception but I have neutralized this with `pass`. The problem is after the `pass` code has been executed the program exits and I need it to continue on and execute the `for` loop on `DIL`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why not:

```
 for code in portfolio_list:
     try:
         share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
         print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value)   
     except KeyError:
         continue
```

OR check dict.get method:

```
 for code in portfolio_list:
     res = EXCHANGE_DATA.get(code, None)
     if res:
         print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, *res)
```

And as @RedBaron mentioned:

```
 for code in portfolio_list:
     if code in EXCHANGE_DATA:
         print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, *EXCHANGE_DATA[code])
```

Comment: You can also be rid of try except block by using something like `if code in EXCHANGE_DATA: #something else: continue`

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka I want to pass a specific key error `KeyError: 'Retail Store'` either I am getting syntax error if doing this ` except KeyError: 'Retail Store': 
      pass ` or Indentation error if doing this ` except KeyError: 'Retail Store'
        pass` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ranadan i guess you need to do something like: except KeyError as exc:  if 'Retail Store' in exc.message: pass else: raise exc You can find my skype in profile so i would able to help you with more examples

Comment: don't you have to use "pass" instead of "continue" as continue goes to next iteration

Answer (score 5):

catch the exception in the loop

```
for code in portfolio_list:
    try:
        share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
        print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value)   
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Edit: The more pythonic way would be to test if the dict has the element first

```
for code in portfolio_list:
    if code in EXCHANGE_DATA:
        share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
        print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value)
```

Comment: It's definitely not the more pythonic way, many pythonistas would prefer the first since it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission. http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#eafp-vs-lbyl

Comment: @RedBaron I disagree, also that case is slightly different, anyway the word pythonic has no clear definition.

Comment: it's only "better to ask for forgiveness than permission" to avoid being too restrictive on what you accept, but in this case a code in ... test is not too restrictive and clearer

Comment: Many ways to do the same thing, To each his own :)